# how to customize ComboBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, combobox, styling

always in a ComboBox a arrow button is show where user click and then a list pop down with value. in WPF can we change the arrow button where i will use my own arrow mage.functionality will be the same. if possible then please show me the xaml for that. thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understand is that you want to customize the arrow of the combobox and have your custom arrow image.If that is the case then you can easily do it by modifying the controltemplate of combobox.

You can edit the default control template by using Expression Blend or copy the same from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and do your modifications.

The Arrow is represented in the default template as a path inside the togglebutton controltemplate Named 
 ***'Arrow'***

.You can change it as you wish to get what you are looking for

```
<Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"/>
                       </Grid>
                    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...i never use Expression Blend so if you please tell the all step which i need to do in Expression Blend in detail that will be great help for me. thanks.